# Sqlite not updating the column values which is specified in where clause

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite

My table contains 3 columns named Name,Day,Month. I want to update these values by specifying them in where clause also.
This is to store Name and Date of Birth of a person.

```
db.update(TABLENAME,cv,NAME+"=? AND "+DAY+"=? AND "+MONTH+"=?",arrayOf(name,dd,mm))
```

This is not working.
The values in 'arrayOf' are old values and values in 'cv' are new values.

Table is

Name   Day   Month

Xyz        5        7

Abc       4        3

Now i want to update Name,Day,Month Values with new values that the user will give using editTexts.
As Name of person can be same.
And Day and Month can also be same of other person.
So i have to use all 3 Column names in where clause. But when i am using 3 columns in where clause it is not updating.

If i write only Name in where clause then it is updating 'Day' and 'Month' values.
But i want to update all 3 values.

Comment: Please most more of your code so we can better identify your problem and if needed replicate it

Comment: Also please tell us what language this is.  It is not obvious to me.

Comment: I am trying to build android app using Kotlin. As this is my first time asking a question sorry for mistakes.